# How to avoid duplicating arguments definition when inheriting from abstract class?

Tags: python, types, code-duplication, abstract-base-class

I have an abstract class written in Python:

```py
class AbsctracClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def method(self, 
        value1: int,
        value2: float,
        value3: str,
        value4: Optional[list] = None,
        value5: Optional[int] = None,
        value6: Optional[float] = None,
        ... etc ...,
        ):
        ''' An abstract method  for an abstract class '''
```

It has one abstract method with a lot of arguments. I know, I know, it is not a good practice to pass lots of arguments to a function, but right now it's irrelevant for my question.

Now I want to write another class that inherits from AbstractClass. And I have to manually duplicate all the arguments with their type hints from an abstract class.

```py
class AnotherClass(AbstractClass):

    def method(self, 
        value1: int,
        value2: float,
        value3: str,
        value4: Optional[list] = None,
        value5: Optional[int] = None,
        value6: Optional[float] = None,
        ... etc ...,
        ):
        return value3 * (value2 + value3)
```

It is not only cumbersome when I have several abstract methods and several classes inherits from it, but `pylint` screams about code duplication. And, to be honest, I agree with him.

Obviously there must be a better way. Is it?

Comment: Doing this manually is better in the long run. Otherwise, use `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: Why is it better in the long run? What if I had to change type hint for some of arguments? I had to refactor all inherited classes then? And pylint screams at *args and **kwargs too when they are inside abstract method inhereted from abstract class.

Comment: You can't change the type hints without violating the Liskov Substitution Principle. The *signature* is the important thing that the ABC dictates.

Comment: Just because the ABC cannot *enforce* the preservation of the signature does not mean you should feel free to change it.

Comment: But I don't want to change type hints. I just feel it redundant to blindly repeat them all each time I inherit ABC.

Answer (score 2):

One solution here could be to use a single `NamedTuple` argument, in both the abstract class and the subclasses. If we have a `NamedTuple` defined like so:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional 

class ArgsTuple(NamedTuple):
    value1: int
    value2: float
    value3: str
    value4: Optional[list] = None
    value5: Optional[int] = None
    value6: Optional[float] = None
```

Then you can refactor your base class like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

# ArgsTuple as defined above

class AbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self, all_args: ArgsTuple):
        ''' An abstract method  for an abstract class '''
```

Your concrete implementations also have to change their signatures for `method`, to keep the signature the same between the base class and the subclass. The way the function is called will also need to change — `method` now only takes one argument, so you will have to wrap all the arguments into `ArgsTuple` before passing them to `method`.

In terms of implementing `method`, you'll now have to unpack the arguments from the `ArgsTuple` within the method. One way of doing this is like this, which some static type-checkers might struggle with (MyPy can infer the types, but if I remember correctly, PyCharm gets lost if you use tuple unpacking):

```
# AbstractClass as refactored above
# ArgsTuple as defined above 

class AnotherClass(AbstractClass):
    def method(self, all_args: ArgsTuple):
        _, value2, value3, *other_args = all_args
        return value3 * (value2 + value3)
```

Another way of doing it would be like this, which some static type-checkers may find easier to handle:

```
# AbstractClass as refactored above
# ArgsTuple as defined above 

class AnotherClass(AbstractClass):
    def method(self, all_args: ArgsTuple):
        value3 = all_args.value3
        return value3 * (all_args.value2 + value3)
```